# Unwind segue causing error - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I have 2 View Controllers. The title of the first is "Pick a Task" and the second is "Room Controller". See below.

[image]

As you can see I have a Modal Segue going from "Pick a task" to "Room Controller". It is set off through the following function when cell 0 is pressed:

```
    if row == 0{
        performSegueWithIdentifier("roomsegue", sender: self)
    }
```

This works fine. In the swift file corresponding to the "Pick a task" View I have the following unwind segue code:

```
@IBAction func unwindToPlayersViewController(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {        

}
```

In the storyboard - in the "Room Controller" view, I CTRL + Dragged from the "Back" button to the exit icon. (In the "Room controller" view as well).

A few options popped up and I clicked on "unwindToPlayersViewController".

Grand.

Now when I run the program, I click on the first cell, I'm directed to the "Room Controller", but when I click "Back" I receive the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and can help me? I've looked at so many tutorials and I've spent aged on this.

EDIT:

The 'Back' button just has the one function, IBAction in the "Pick a Task" View Class, as shown above.

The name of my project is "MetingRooms"

Comment: The back button in the storyboard just work you don't need to drag it to exit

Comment: It is a button, I just renamed it to "Back". It could  be "Cancel" or any name  really. But it does not know what it's function is until defined.

Comment: Does the button "back" has some other (old) connections to other ib actions?

Comment: No, it only has unwind IBAction which is located in the "Pick a Task" View. Is this right?

Comment: @Jacobson yes you were right, thanks a million